# Do I need a travel insurance if I'm having a transit flight in France (to outside EU)?

Tags: transit, france, insurance

Do I need travel insurance if I have a transit flight of about 5 hours in France (to outside EU)? I'm not from one of the countries for which a Schengen transit visa is necessary, but I had a question regarding travel insurance and if it would still be required in this case.

Edit: I arrive from outside EU/Schengen and have a connection at Paris in France to another country outside EU/Schengen. The 5 hours is the duration of the layover at Paris. Both flights are on the same ticket. I can only remain in the international zone at the airport, so I don't have to go through passport control. Also I do need a visa if I wanted to enter France.

Comment: Even when not needed, it is better to always have travel insurance on long and far travels.

Comment: Typically the same rules regarding documentation can apply to visa-free travellers as to visa applicants, although the former may (often/usually) not be asked for such documents on arrival. As @Willeke comments, travel insurance is a good idea irrespective of whether you might be asked to prove you have it

Comment: Can you make it clearer what your actual itinerary is? My guess is that you arrive from outside EU/Schengen and have a connection at an airport somewhere in France to another country outside EU/Schengen, but I’m really not sure. Also are the 5 hours the connection time or the duration of one of the flights? Which airport are you connecting at? Are both flights on the same ticket? Can you remain airside or do you have to go through passport control? What’s your citizenship (nationality)?

Comment: @jcaron You're right, I should have given more details. Check my edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will not go through passport control and don’t need a visa, travel insurance is not required by Schengen or national authorities, and nobody will ask for proof they you have insurance (at least not in respect of your transit through Paris).

However it remains a very good idea (to put it lightly) to have travel insurance. Note that you may be covered automatically, especially if you pay for your ticket with a credit card (many include travel insurance), or in other insurance policies. If you don’t, travel insurance is often cheap and quick to get.